# How to fixed the topmenu component?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I need the topmenu component to be fixed when scrolling the page. And the toolbar component disappears when scrolling the page.

How to do it?

html:

```
<app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
<mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav-content fxLayout="column">
        <app-topmenu></app-topmenu>
        <div fxFlex="1 1 auto">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <app-footer ></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

css:

```
mat-sidenav-container {
    min-height      : calc(100% - 60px);
    height          : calc(100% - 60px);
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}

mat-sidenav-content {
    min-height: 100%;
    height    : 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for to position fixed the top menu.

```
app-topmenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: But this will close the toolbar component.

Comment: you can adjust the postion as per your requirement or can you show me demo of your code via stackbliz ? so I can give you proper solution.